# How to change "Billing details" title to a title with html tags on WooCommerce checkout page with a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to change "Billing details" title on the checkout page with a hook, i want the title to contain HTML tags like : img and  div tags.

this is what i tried, it change the title but consider the html tags as regular text.

```
function filter_gettext( $translated, $original_text, $domain ) {   
    // Is admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $translated;
    
    // No match
    if ( $original_text != 'Billing details' ) return $translated;
    
    // Match
    $translated = '<div>123</div>';
    
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```

expected output is : 123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter('esc_html', 'billing_details_title', 10, 2);

function billing_details_title($safe_text, $text) {

    if ('Billing details' === $text && is_checkout()) {
        return '<div>123</div>';
    }
    return $safe_text;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, this code does not change the billing details title

Comment: it was cache! , working thanks a lot!